# Caching the sessionfactory

Tags: c#, asp.net, nhibernate, caching

As far as I've gathered (read: measured), building the configuration and the sessionfactory by far takes the most time in executing a query using nhibernate. Is there anything against making the sessionfactory static, so it will only be configured once per appDomain?

I know there are locking and racing issues when using this approach, but personally I don't see where this would break my application when using this approach on the sessionfactory.

The reason I am asking this is because it's really hard to test for possible threading issues, as it doesn't occur all the time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Session factory should be started at the application start indeed. You could check the [best practices here](http://www.hibernate.org/363.html#A4).

Comment: Thanks. That link is very nice as well, finally a good explanation of good and bad singleton implementations ;-)